# $_POST method request limit

Tags: php

```
if($_POST['body']) {
//do my stuff
}
```

But let's say i wanna limit $_POST['body'] access to 100 per user(IP).
Every time same user (same IP) access/try $_POST['body']) ir count's him and if limit reached (this time limit 100) display error message and with that say that he can access to $_POST['body'] after 10 minutes.

First idea came to mind is to use MySQL, log every IP and count there access times. But imagine if site have many visitors how much IP it logs. So, it's possible to do that without mysql ? If yes, please provide script.

If something don't understand, jusk ask, and sorry for english :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to save this server-side, and a database tabe won't grow too much if you clean it up properly.

You could use cookies or sessions (they are cookie-based), but this is client side and people could just delete or alter the cookie.

Comment: You mean MySQL cron/cleanup after some time ?

Comment: Cron job to run every now and again to delete records older than 10minutes

Answer (score 3):

Is using sessions sufficient for you?

```
if($_POST['body']){
    if($_SESSION['counter'] < 100){
       //...
       $_SESSION['counter']++;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that a different IP doesn't mean different User. Many users can be behind the same Proxy, giving them all the same IP address.

Comment: +1 because it's what I was going to suggest, and I would have made the same point about IPs and proxies too. But don't forget to do `session_start()` beforehand!

Comment: If user just cleans cookies or refuses them for this site, this approach won't work.

Comment: @Palantir Sessions are server side and not client side so it doesn't matter with sessions if the user doesn't accept cookies.

Comment: @m4rc please, go read the manual. "A visitor accessing your web site is assigned a unique id, the so-called session id. This is either stored in a cookie on the user side or is propagated in the URL." http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php Delete the cookie, and you destroy the session.

Comment: @Palantir My mistake, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be DB too. Have you tried [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)?